# "No credentials" error when using Storage (S3) from aws-amplify for node

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I´m getting the error "No credentials" when trying to GET an image from a bucket in S3:

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import { Auth, Storage } from 'aws-amplify'


componentDidMount(){

Storage.get('random-image.jpg')
                .then(data => {
                    console.log(data)
                }).catch(err => console.log(err))
         
}
```

For what i´ve heard I need to add an identity federated pool, I´m struggling to understand what is the difference between aws-amplify and aws-sdk and particularly where exactly in my app I have to put the identity federated pool url to be able to make it work.

Here´s my code until now, I´m using cognito service to allow users to register and login, and S3 for the user to be able to upload images.

```js
Amplify.configure({
    Auth: {
        mandatorySignId: true,
        region: config.cognito.REGION,
        userPoolId: config.cognito.USER_POOL_ID,
        userPoolWebClientId: config.cognito.APP_CLIENT_ID
    },
    Storage: {
        AWSS3: {
            bucket: config.s3.bucket,
            region: config.s3.region, 
        }
    }
})
```

However now I need to implement to the necessary code to be able to do a GET request to the S3 bucket and from what i´ve read I need to open an federated identity pool which is related to my cognito user pool, and then paste this code in the app:

```js
AWS.config.region = 'eu-west-2'; // Region
AWS.config.credentials = new AWS.CognitoIdentityCredentials({
    IdentityPoolId: 'eu-west-2:70614759-5f98-48*******',
});
```

However that is not `aws-amplify` but `aws-sdk`. I´ve tried importing aws-sdk and pasting that code but is not working.
Am I able to put that information in the `Amplify.configure` statement? Following this page https://aws-amplify.github.io/docs/js/storage it says I can, so I did it:

```js
Auth: {
        mandatorySignId: true,
        region: config.cognito.REGION,
        userPoolId: config.cognito.USER_POOL_ID,
        userPoolWebClientId: config.cognito.APP_CLIENT_ID
        // add the identity federated:
        identityPoolId: config.cognito.IDENTITY_POOL
    },
```

And now it gives me `Missing credentials in config`